# Changing old join to new join

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL so any help is greatly appreciated. I have a query that seems to be working that has old style joins, and I need to change it to new style joins.  the current query is like:

```
SELECT
    STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS     .DISASTER_NUMBER,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS     .PW_NUMBER,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS.SITE_NUMBER,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS          .PROJECT_AMOUNT,
    STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS  .MITIGATION_ACTIVITY_STATUS
FROM
    STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS,
    STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS,
    STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS
WHERE 
    ( STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS.PA_PROJECT_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_ID  )
    AND
    ( STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS.DISASTER_ID = STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS.DISASTER_ID  )
    AND
    ( STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS.PA_MITIGATION_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_ID  )
    AND
    ( STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_ID = STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS.PA_MITIGATION_ID  )
    AND
    ( STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.DISASTER_ID = STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS.DISASTER_ID  )
    AND
    ( STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS.PA_PROJECT_ID  )
    AND
    ( STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_SITE_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS.PA_PROJECT_SITE_ID  )
```

My attempt to convert is below.  I don't know where to put the extra conditions because they are not 1 to 1 with tables.

```
FROM
    STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS
    JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS ON STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.DISASTER_ID = STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS.DISASTER_ID  
    JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS ON STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS.PA_PROJECT_ID 
    JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS ON STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_SITE_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS.PA_PROJECT_SITE_ID
    JOIN STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS ON STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS.PA_PROJECT_ID = STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS.PA_MITIGATION_ID
    JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS ON (
        STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS        .DISASTER_ID      = STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS.DISASTER_ID AND 
        STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS.PA_MITIGATION_ID = STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS     .PA_PROJECT_ID AND
        STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS   .PA_PROJECT_ID    = STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS     .PA_PROJECT_ID
    )
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Join syntax is readily available on Google.

Comment: Where's your attempt at converting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `,` to `INNER JOIN`s with `ON` condition:

```
SELECT
STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS.DISASTER_NUMBER,
STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS.PW_NUMBER,
STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS.SITE_NUMBER,
STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS.PROJECT_AMOUNT,
STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS.MITIGATION_ACTIVITY_STATUS
FROM
STAR.PA_PROJECT_DIMENSIONS PD
INNER JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_FACTS PF ON PD.PA_PROJECT_ID=PF.PA_PROJECT_ID
INNER JOIN STAR.V_DISASTER_DIMENSIONS DD ON DD.DISASTER_ID=PF.DISASTER_ID
INNER JOIN STAR.PA_MITIGATION_DIMENSIONS MD ON MD.PA_MITIGATION_ID=PF.PA_PROJECT_ID
INNER JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_FACTS PSF ON PSF.PA_PROJECT_ID=MD.PA_MITIGATION_ID 
                                         AND PSF.DISASTER_ID=DD.DISASTER_ID 
                                         AND PSF.PA_PROJECT_ID=PD.PA_PROJECT_ID  
INNER JOIN STAR.PA_PROJECT_SITE_DIMENSIONS PSD ON PSD.PA_PROJECT_SITE_ID=PSF.PA_PROJECT_SITE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jibin.  I found the basic structure but couldn't figure out which conditions go where.  Can you tell me why you decided to put the 3 on project site facts please?

Comment: @HunterClark Beacause you had 3 conditions on project site facts table,if you want you can move it to individual tables `ON` condition with `AND`, that will also give you the same result.

Comment: Also don't I have to put a parenthesis around the ON with multiple conditions?

Comment: @HunterClark Nope, you don't have to, you can add multipe conditions by using just `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from  
a,b
where a.z = b.y
```

would be written as

```
Select * from
a
INNER JOIN
b
ON a.z = b.y
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Just start with the facts table and join related tables on foreign key = key.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use table aliases to get the query more readable. Also use some lowercase letters, too.

Then just write the table names (or the aliases) on paper and draw a line for each condition from one table to the other. Then pick one table to start with, e.g. `pa_project_site_dimensions` which is only linked to one table.

```
SELECT
  dd.disaster_number,
  pd.pw_number,
  psd.site_number,
  psf.project_amount,
  md.mitigation_activity_status
FROM star.pa_project_site_dimensions psd
JOIN star.pa_project_site_facts psf ON psf.pa_project_site_id = psd.pa_project_site_id
JOIN star.v_disaster_dimensions dd ON dd.disaster_id = psf.disaster_id
JOIN star.pa_mitigation_dimensions md ON md.pa_mitigation_id = psf.pa_project_id
JOIN star.pa_project_dimensions pd ON pd.pa_project_id = psf.pa_project_id
JOIN star.pa_project_facts pf ON  pf.disaster_id = dd.disaster_id
                              AND pf.pa_project_id = md.pa_mitigation_id
                              AND pf.pa_project_id = pd.pa_project_id
;
```

However, this is a strange query. First of all there is no limiting condition, you simply join all records, rather than retrieving data for, say, one particular project.

Moreover, you deal with several dimensions. Obviously a project has facts (pa_project_facts) and dimensions (`pa_project_dimensions`). With 5 facts and 3 dimensions you'd get 15 rows with all their combinations. Then there are also project sites it seems (maybe a table `pa_project_sites` we don't see in the query). Either that project site has facts on its own (`pa_project_site_facts`) that you also combine with all rows, or a project site is linked to a project fact via `pa_project_site_facts`, but then `pa_project_facts` wouldn't have to be joined by `pa_project_id` only, but also by some fact ID.

Also this looks strange: `md.pa_mitigation_id = psf.pa_project_id`. Is a mitigation the same as a project?

So after all have a look at *all* columns that need to be joined on. Think about how the tables are related and if you are not building combinations that make no sense.